# 3 images not aligning horizontally whilst using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, image, formatting

I am attempting to implement three images horizontally into a HTML website. However when i format it using CSS nothing is happening, I am very confused as it should theoretically work. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me out, thank you.

HTML page image part:

```
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="gosportSunset.jpg" alt="Sunset" style="width:33%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="gosport.jpg" alt="Gosport" style="width:33%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="gosportRace.jpg" alt="Race" style="width:33%">
  </div>
</div>
</p>
```

CSS image formatting part:

```
/* Three image containers  */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean nothing work ? If I'm guessing right, you add `img { display block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` to `.column`

Comment: @amauryHanser I have implemented your line of code and still nothing has happened

Comment: @phpNew *nothing has happened*... it's not clear. Are you even sure that your css is added to your html document ?

Comment: Have you linked to the CSS file in the head of the HTML file or put the CSS in the HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

If the grid is not working try to add `box-sizing: border-box;` in `.column`

```
.column {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 5px;
   box-sizing:border-box;  // important
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i have added your code, but there is still no change to the image layout

Comment: did you removed `width: 33%` from `img` and give them height using `img { height: 300px }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using div structure you can try something with ul & li, also make use of "column-count" property using which you can define the number of columns you want in a horizontal row.

Refer link for more understanding about "column-count" property:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
 column-count: 3;
 list-style: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <ul>
  <li>
    <img src="gosportSunset.jpg" alt="Sunset "/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="gosport.jpg" alt="Gosport" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="gosportRace.jpg" alt="Race" />
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```